# How to debug if fluentd not sending logs to ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, fluent-bit

Fluentd is installed via Bitnami Helm chart, version - 1.13.3-debian-10-r30 . As a next step, I'm trying to push logs from Fluentd to Logstash but I see these errors reported and not sure what to make of it and I don't see logs pushed to ELK.

What am I missing here, thank you.

```
[elasticsearch] 'index_name fluentd' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'index_name: fluentd' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'template_name ' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'template_name: ' doesn't have tag placeholder
```

**Elasticsearch conf:**

```
elk-output.conf: |
<match **>
    @type elasticsearch
    @id elasticsearch
    @log_level debug
    host elk-host3.my.org.com
    port 9200
    flush_interval 5s
    logstash_format true
    scheme https
    ssl_verify false
</match>
```

**Input or source configuration:**

```
  <source>
    @type tail
    path /var/log/containers/*.log
    # exclude Fluentd logs
    exclude_path /var/log/containers/*fluentd*.log
    pos_file /opt/bitnami/fluentd/logs/buffers/fluentd-docker.pos
    tag kubernetes.*
    read_from_head true
    <parse>
      #@type json
      @type regexp
      expression ^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.[^Z]*Z)\s(?<stream>[^\s]+)\s(?<character>[^\s])\s(?<log>.*)$
      #expression ^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.[^Z]*Z)\s(?<stream>[^\s]+)\s(?<character>[^\s])\s(?<message>.*)$
      #expression ^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<message>.*) (?<log_type>[^ ]*) (?<projectID>[^ ]*) (?<tag>[^ ]*) (?<log>[^ ]*)$
      time_key time
      #time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      #time_keep on
    </parse>
  </source>
```

**curl -k https://elk-host3.my.org.com:9200**

```
{
  "name" : "elk-host3.my.org.com",
  "cluster_name" : "drpelk",
  "cluster_uuid" : "OUibZPqUQBi9nq6TBDHJ9w",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.0",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "51e9d6f22758d0374a0f3f5c6e8f3a7997850f96",
    "build_date" : "2020-11-09T21:30:33.964949Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Detailed logs from the fluentd pod:

```
fluentd 06:35:33.67 Welcome to the Bitnami fluentd container
fluentd 06:35:33.67 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-fluentd
fluentd 06:35:33.67 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-fluentd/issues
fluentd 06:35:33.67
fluentd 06:35:33.67 INFO  ==> ** Starting Fluentd setup **
fluentd 06:35:33.68 INFO  ==> ** Fluentd setup finished! **

fluentd 06:35:33.68 INFO  ==> ** Starting Fluentd **
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/opt/bitnami/fluentd/conf/fluentd.conf"
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-concat' version '2.5.0'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions' version '0.0.13'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '5.0.5'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-grafana-loki' version '1.2.16'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kafka' version '0.16.3'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter' version '2.7.2'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser' version '1.0.0'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '2.0.1'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '2.4.0'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '1.6.0'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.5'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.13.3'
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [warn]: !! The environment variable 'K8S_NODE_NAME' is not set to the node name which can affect the API server and watch efficiency !!
2023-06-03 06:35:34 +0000 [info]: brokers has been set: ["broker.myorg.com:9092"]
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [info]: [elasticsearch] 'flush_interval' is configured at out side of <buffer>. 'flush_mode' is set to 'interval' to keep existing behaviour
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'host elk-host3.my.org.com' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'host: elk-host3.my.org.com' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'index_name fluentd' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'index_name: fluentd' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'template_name ' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'template_name: ' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'logstash_prefix logstash' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'logstash_prefix: logstash' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'logstash_dateformat %Y.%m.%d' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'logstash_dateformat: %Y.%m.%d' has timestamp placeholders, but chunk key 'time' is not configured
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'logstash_dateformat %Y.%m.%d' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'logstash_dateformat: %Y.%m.%d' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'deflector_alias ' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'deflector_alias: ' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'application_name default' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'application_name: default' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'ilm_policy_id logstash-policy' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'ilm_policy_id: logstash-policy' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] Need substitution: false
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [debug]: [elasticsearch] 'host_placeholder elk-host3.my.org.com' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'host_placeholder: elk-host3.my.org.com' doesn't have tag placeholder
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [warn]: define <match fluent.**> to capture fluentd logs in top level is deprecated. Use <label @FLUENT_LOG> instead
2023-06-03 06:35:35 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  elk-output.conf: |
  <match fluent.**>
    @type null
  </match>
  <source>
    @type http
    port 9880
  </source>
  <source>
    @type tail
    path "/var/log/containers/*.log"
    exclude_path /var/log/containers/*fluentd*.log
    pos_file "/opt/bitnami/fluentd/logs/buffers/fluentd-docker.pos"
    tag "kubernetes.*"
    read_from_head true
    <parse>
      @type "regexp"
      expression ^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.[^Z]*Z)\s(?<stream>[^\s]+)\s(?<character>[^\s])\s(?<log>.*)$
      time_key "time"
      unmatched_lines
    </parse>
  </source>
  <filter kubernetes.**>
    @type kubernetes_metadata
  </filter>
  <match **>
    @type kafka2
    brokers kafkabroker01.my.org.com:9092,kafkabroker02.my.org.com:9092,kafkabroker03.my.org.com:9092
    use_event_time false
    topic_key "output_logs"
    default_topic "output_logs"
    compression_codec "gzip"
    max_send_limit_bytes 3000000
    <format>
      @type "json"
    </format>
    <buffer output_logs>
      @type "file"
      path "/opt/bitnami/fluentd/logs/buffers/"
      flush_interval 5s
      flush_at_shutdown true
      chunk_limit_size 2MB
    </buffer>
  </match>
  <match **>
    @type elasticsearch
    @id elasticsearch
    @log_level "debug"
    host "elk-host3.my.org.com"
    port 9200
    type_name "_doc"
    flush_interval 5s
    logstash_format false
    scheme https
    ssl_verify false
    <buffer>
      flush_interval 5s
    </buffer>
  </match>
```